# In Nightwatch, `.url()` blocks assertions for too long

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nightwatch.js

It appears that using `browser.url()` (http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#url) to navigate causes the WebDriver client to wait until the page is fully loaded - however I have assertions I want to make before that point.

```
"Shows splash screen for a few seconds": function(client) {
  client
    .url(client.testURL)
    // at this point, the splash has already come and gone, so
    // this next command times out
    .waitForElementVisible('#splash img', 10000)
    .waitForElementNotVisible('#splash', 10000);
},
```

Is this possible?  I think my only other option is to disable the splash in a test scenario.

I'm running these tests on Firefox v45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting Firefox profile preferences as shown in below

https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/748

The preference you need to set is `webdriver.load.strategy` to be `unstable`. But this means that waiting for page to load is now all your business

```
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');

function setProfile(browser, profile, callback) {
    profile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
        browser.options.desiredCapabilities['firefox_profile'] = encodedProfile;
        callback();
    });
}

function setFirefoxProfile(browser, done) {
    var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference('webdriver.load.strategy', 'unstable');

    setProfile(browser, profile, done);
}


// and in my test module
before: function (browser, done) {
    setFirefoxProfile(browser, done);
}
```

Comment: Incorporating this did not change anything - Firefox still waits for a full page load.  It is possible that my version of Firefox was before or after this feature, but I have spent so much time trying to configure Nightwatch with the latest Firefox and failing that I am going to stick with v45.

Comment: Latest firefox would need `geckodriver` and your version is before geckodriver and the latest one will not with this profile setting. Can you check in the opened firefox if the profile setting was actually applied? Go to `about:config` and filter for the property we set and check the value

Comment: There are a bunch of webdriver preferences, but `webdriver.load.strategy` does not appear.  It is probably a waste your time helping me to configure an old version of Firefox - I may just migrate to Chrome.

Comment: Is there a similar load strategy flag for Chrome or is it not required?

Comment: There is, `capabilities.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "none");` for chrome. You will have to check how to set capability for chrome in nightwatch.js

Comment: I set `{ desiredCapabilities: { pageLoadStrategy: 'none' } }` in my Nightwatch conf to get the desired behaviour.